# SonarQube : Execution of several Sonar analysis at same time, on same project. Different versions

Tags: sonarqube

I want to have Sonar analysis being performed on twice on the same Maven project at the same time, but different versions.

i.e. GAV details

```
<groupId>com.test.exm</groupId>
<artifactId>exm001</artifactId>
<version>1.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

AND

```
<groupId>com.test.exm</groupId>
<artifactId>exm001</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

This gives the error though...

> Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: The project is already
>   being analysed.   at
>   org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectLock.start(ProjectLock.java:55)

Please don't ask why I have snapshot 1.4.0 and 1.5.0 at the same time.
Its a legacy build thing going on in the background.

I would have thought the semaphore lock used would include the version number, not just the artifact and groupID.

I've found this defect...

https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2761

I could turn off sonar for the legacy stuff, but I'd sooner see if there is a fix I could make to allow Sonar to do the analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you can use the `sonar.branch` [property](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) on the legacy version of your project.

Comment: Thanks for this: I've found another Stack question from you answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466102/how-to-generate-two-sonar-reports-from-the-same-project